# How to display timetable

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

I have a table "Timetable" as following:

[image]

I'm using Hibernate in my project. So When I query this table, I get list containing data for Class, Teacher, Course and Room .
But I'm facing a problem, I don't know a way to print the timetable on screen, as timetables are usually displayed.

Timetables are usually displayed like following.

[image]

Can anyone solve my this problem?

Comment: Are you asking how to write a query that produces data suitable for display? If so, show us what such a timetable would look like.

Comment: I'm not asking about query. I'm asking about displaying it on console or on JSF page. I'm adding a picture of a timetable display.

Comment: What field in the table has the day information ( Moday, Tuesday etc.)?

Comment: Oh sorry. Just forget to include this field in snap. Day ranges from 1-5 for Monday-Friday.

Answer (score 0):

See at the PrimeFaces Schedule component:
http://www.primefaces.org/showcase-labs/ui/scheduleLazy.jsf

It's easy to use and was cool for me.

Answer (score 0):

Your table can be represented as a list of TimeSlot. Each TimeSlot object in the list has a timeRange (start and end time), and a 5 events (monday, thursday ...). The TimeSlots have a natural ordering which is the ordering of the start of their time range.

Iterate through all the rows in the table. For each row, find an existing TimeSlot with the same time range, or create it if it doesn't exist yet, and store it in the list of time slots. Then set the appropriate day field of the TimeSlot depending on the day of your row. Sort the list.

Once you have this sorted list of TimeSlot objects, displaying the table is just a matter of iterating through the list of TimeSlot, and to generate one table row per TimeSlot.